# Hyperjaxb3: Is it possible to avoid Items table/class creation on PO sample?

Tags: java, hibernate, xsd, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I'm trying to avoid join classes creation. I tested some binding configuration but can't seem to get it done.

In [PO Sample from git sources](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3) on tag 0.6.0 ejb/tests/po-customized, I tried some configuration.

First, I added join-column as one-to-many mapping in bindings

**bindings.xjb**

```
...
        <hj:persistence>
            <hj:default-one-to-many>
                <orm:join-column />
                <!-- <orm:join-table /> -->
            </hj:default-one-to-many>
        </hj:persistence>
...
```

This only change the annotation in getItem, from JoinTable to JoinColumn.

Also, I tried to override xsd mapping by telling it to add a list directly. the following code doesn't work, but it's the general idea of what I've been trying... (never get something like it to work)

**bindings.xjb**

```
...
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='PurchaseOrderType']">
            <hj:entity>
                <orm:table name="po" />
            </hj:entity>
            <jaxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='items']">
                <hj:one-to-many>
                    <orm:join-column name="PO_ID" />
                </hj:one-to-many>
            </jaxb:bindings>
        </jaxb:bindings>
...
```

Is it possible to generate **PurchaseOrderType** with this definition? (some xml annotations omitted)

```
...
public class PurchaseOrderType ... {

    protected USAddress shipTo;
    protected USAddress billTo;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="items")
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    protected List<Item> items;

    protected XMLGregorianCalendar orderDate;
    protected Long hjid;

...
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Item.class, cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL
    })
    public List<Item> getItems() {
...
```

Note in this code, I'm pointing directly to generated Item, and not Items.Item.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I prefer to use only Hyperjaxb3 plugin. I know there is [another plugin out there](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin) that can do something like this, but I don't know how it will interact with Hyperjaxb3. If someone has previous experience doing this, please comment

Answer (score 0):

This worked in HJ2 but was is not implemented in HJ3 yet. Here's an [issue](http://jira.highsource.org/browse/HJIII-74) for this.

In principle, the `XmlElementWrapper` plugin you mention is a way to go. I've just never tested it with HJ3.

If you want this feature, please file an issue [here](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/issues), I'll see what I can do.

**Disclosure:** I'm the author of Hyperjaxb3.